# How to use logical operators in DRF's DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

Since [DRF==3.9--(release notes)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#390) we have got an option to combine/compose the permission classes in our views.

```
class MyViewSet(...):
    permission_classes = [FooPermission & BarPermission]
```

I did try something like this,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (

        'utils.permissions.FooPermission' & 'utils.permissions.BarPermission',

    ),

    # other settings

}
```

and python raised exception

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

So,

How can I use combined permission as global permission using [**`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_permission_classes) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new *variable* by combining those classes and referenced the same in the **`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`**,

```
# utils/permissions.py

from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class FooPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # check permissions

        return ...


class BarPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # check permissions

        return ...


CombinedPermission = FooPermission & BarPermission

# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (

        'utils.permissions.CombinedPermission',

    ),

    # other settings

}
```

#### Note

- You can use *"any supported"* bitwise operators instead of ***`&`*** in this example.

Comment: Fantastic! Note that this is also possible `DebugApiPermissions = (IsAuthenticated | IsLocalRequest) & DjangoModelPermissions`